# Approach to move files from s3 to sharepoint

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sharepoint

I am faced with a challenge to move json files from AWS s3 bucket to sharepoint.
If anyone can share inputs on if this is doable and what's the simplest of approach to accomplish this(thinking python script in AWS lambda).
Thanks in Advance

Comment: For the Sharepoint end these seem to be promising: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/78034/how-to-connect-python-program-to-sharepoint-rest-a.html, https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/.

For the AWS end I did not search, but I am sure there is a lot out there.

Answer (score 0):

Using S3 boto API, you can download the files from any bucket to local drive.
Then using Office365 API, you can upload that local file to Share point. Make sure you check the disk space in local before doing the download option.